# how to set validation in angular formly

Tags: angular-formly

i am creating a form using formly there are two input text box and i want that both the text box should not be empty.How to set validation

my code is:

```
 form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
      userFields: FormlyFieldConfig = [{
    className: 'row',
    fieldGroup: [{
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        key: 'identity',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            validate: true,
            required: true,
            type: 'email',
            label: 'Email address',
            placeholder: 'Enter email',


        }
    }, {
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        key: 'password',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
            validate: true,
            required: true,
            type: 'password',
            label: 'Password',
            placeholder: 'Password',
            validationsCustom: 'validation.html'
        }


    }]
  }];
```

Comment: What's the expected and the actual outcome?

Comment: i want to set the validation in input box.....so that when a user leaves any box blank an alert will be displayed that the field cant be empty.But i am unable to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should include **FormlyModule** with some configuration to your **AppModule**. In your case, you should include error name **required** and message **'This field is required.'**
For example:

```
import { FormlyModule } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormlyModule.forRoot({
      validationMessages: [
        { name: 'required', message: 'This field is required.' },
      ],
    }),
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

More information related to validation you can see there https://formly.dev/guide/validation